# Trying to get values from multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a very basic expense tracker by building off the foundation of a todo app with vanilla Javascript. I'm having trouble isolating the value of all three input bars and getting them to display on the page. At the moment I'm getting 3 [objectHTMLInputElement] and undefined. I'd just like to know if I'm on the right track or if there's an easier way to isolate multiple input values and get them to display on the page. If somebody could point me in the right direction that'd be awesome. Thanks!

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('add-btn');
addButton.addEventListener('click', add);
let inputName = document.getElementById('input-name');
let inputDate = document.getElementById('input-date');
let inputAmount = document.getElementById('input-amount');
let inputAll = document.querySelectorAll('.input-all');

let expenses = [
]

function add() {
  let inputs = inputAll.value;
  if (inputs == '') {
    return true;
  }
  expenses.push(inputs);
  displayExpenses();
}

function remove() {
}

function displayExpenses() {
  let expensesUl = document.getElementById('expenses-ul');
  expensesUl.innerHTML = `${inputName}${inputDate}${inputAmount}`;

  for (var i = 0; i < expenses.length; i++) {
    let expensesLi = document.createElement('li');
    expensesLi.innerHTML = expenses[i];
    expensesUl.appendChild(expensesLi);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.headings {
  text-align: center;
}

.headings h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.headings h2 {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

#input-name {
  width: 50%;
}

#input-date {
  width: 18%;
  margin-right: 160px;
}

#input-amount {
  width: 18%;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

#add-btn {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Expense Tracker</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="headings">
    <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
    <h2>Add A New Item</h2>
  </div>

  <form>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input class="input-all" id="input-name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Date:</label>
    <input class="input-all" id="input-date">
    <label>Amount:</label>
    <input class="input-all" id="input-amount">
  </form>

  <button id="add-btn">Add Expense</button>

  <ul id="expenses-ul"></ul>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You get `[object HTMLInputElement]` if you forget to use `.value` to get the value of the input.

Comment: `${inputName}${inputDate}${inputAmount}` should be `${inputName.value}${inputDate.value}${inputAmount.value}`

Comment: I think that you got `[NodeList]` that  consists of 3 index everyone have `[HTMLInputElement]` so you need to loop through this node list to get the value of every input element + also you can't set `Object` as innerHTML of an element you need to set the value of it not the whole Object

Comment: Adding .value worked and now the inputs are showing up on the page in one line. However, it also says undefined underneath that line every time I hit the add button.

Comment: What do you expect `inputAll.value` to be? It's a collection of all the inputs, not a single input, so it doesn't have a value.

Comment: You should be using the `expenses` array to display the values, you are using global variables. Avoid global variables as much as you can!

Comment: Samridh - could you please expand on this a bit please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  const output = document.getElementById('output');
  const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
  output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
});
```

```css
.wrap{
  display: flex;
}

#output{
  margin-left:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:dashed;
  border-color:#FFAC55;
  padding:5px;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <form id="form">
      <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
      <label for="date">Date:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="role" name="role"> <br>
      <label for="lname">Amount:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"><br><br>
      <input id="btn" type="button" value="Print all value">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <pre id="output">
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When using `document.querySelectorAll` it's return a `[NodeList]` that consists of all selected elements on the other side there's also `document.getElementsByClassName` that return `[HTMLCollection]` -  whatever you used you need to loop through to get the value of every selected input
2. When you passed `[HTMLInputElement]` as innerHTML of `expensesUl` it's will return the element object name not the value of this element because you are not selected any property of this object so you can't set an object as `innerHTML` of html element

- if you want the right way of this part it's will be like that

```
let inputName = document.getElementById('input-name');
let inputDate = document.getElementById('input-date');
let inputAmount = document.getElementById('input-amount');
let expensesUl = document.getElementById('expenses-ul');
//this will give you empty string because they aren't get a value yet
expensesUl.innerHTML = `name = ${inputName.value}, date =  ${inputDate.value}, amoute = ${inputAmount.value}`;
```

- but now because we are selected all elements we are not need to select every input one by one anymore we will make a loop so we will loop through `inputAll` var to get the value of `[HTMLInputElement]` object

```
let addButton = document.getElementById('add-btn');
addButton.addEventListener('click', add);

function add() {
  let inputAll = document.querySelectorAll('.input-all');
  for(var i of inputAll) {
     if (i.value == '') {
        return "Sorry you need to fill all inputs"
     }
  }
  displayExpenses(inputAll);
}
function displayExpenses(elements) {
  let expensesUl = document.getElementById('expenses-ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let expensesLi = document.createElement('li');
    expensesLi.innerHTML = elements[i].value
    expensesUl.appendChild(expensesLi);
  }
}
```

- at the example above i removed `expenses` array but if you want to use it to take the value of the inputs you can make it like that

```
let addButton = document.getElementById('add-btn');
addButton.addEventListener('click', add);

function add() {
  let inputAll = document.querySelectorAll('.input-all');
  let expenses = []
  for(var i of inputAll) {
     if (i.value == '') {
        return "Sorry you need to fill all inputs"
     }
     expenses.push(i.value)
  }
  displayExpenses(expenses);
}
function displayExpenses(values) {
  let expensesUl = document.getElementById('expenses-ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    let expensesLi = document.createElement('li');
    expensesLi.innerHTML = values[i]
    expensesUl.appendChild(expensesLi);
  }
}
```

- the whole code should to be like that

```
let addButton = document.getElementById('add-btn');
addButton.addEventListener('click', add);
let inputName = document.getElementById('input-name');
let inputDate = document.getElementById('input-date');
let inputAmount = document.getElementById('input-amount');
let inputAll = document.querySelectorAll('.input-all');
let expenses = []

function add() {
  for(var i of inputAll) {
     if (i.value == '') {
        return true
     }
     expenses.push(i.value)
  }
  displayExpenses();
}

function displayExpenses() {
  let expensesUl = document.getElementById('expenses-ul');
  expensesUl.innerHTML = `${inputName.value}, ${inputDate.value}, ${inputAmount.value}`;

  for (var i = 0; i < expenses.length; i++) {
    let expensesLi = document.createElement('li');
    expensesLi.innerHTML = expenses[i];
    expensesUl.appendChild(expensesLi);
  }
}
```

- about `document.getElementsByClassName`, `document.querySelectorAll` one deferant is that you can use  array methods like `forEach()` with `document.querySelectorAll` while you can't do that with `document.getElementsByClassName`